# Does Javascript DOM OffsetWidth vary on different devices?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to increase the width of an object as I click the button, while using Javascript. It works perfectly on mobile view and when it comes to the laptop view, it reduces it's width at first and then starts to work. you'll see what I'm saying just run the code.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var redObj = document.querySelector('.line');
var currentWidth = (redObj.offsetWidth / 33.6);
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentWidth += 10;
  console.log(currentWidth);
  redObj.style.width = currentWidth + 'px';
});
```

```css
.line {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<button class="btn">Increase</button>
```

Comment: The first time the button is clicked, you take the width (30px), divide by 33.6 (= ~0.9), and then add 10. This sets the width to ~10.9px.

Answer (score 0):

It is 30 to begin with so you get 30/33+10 size when you click.

Try this

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var redObj = document.querySelector('.line');

console.log(redObj.offsetWidth)
var currentWidth = redObj.offsetWidth;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentWidth += 10;
  console.log(currentWidth);
  redObj.style.width = currentWidth + 'px';
});
```

```css
.line {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<button class="btn">Increase</button>
```

Comment: why is it 30/33 tho. and what did the Math.max() do?

Comment: It is 20 to begin with, then you divide it by  33.6. Then when you click you add 10 to that number. So it is pretty logical you have a smaller width. The math max is unnecessary

Comment: You need to explain us why you wanted to divide by 33.6 to begin with